# Create Virtual network gateway in an existing Vnet using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create Virtual network gateway for an existing Vnet using terraform. Can someone help me with Code.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I get an error:    [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mazurerm_virtual_network_gateway.test: Provider doesn't support resource: azurerm_virtual_network_gateway[0

Comment: @alok If the answer is helpful or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try updating your azurerm Terraform provider

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name = "GatewaySubnet"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${var.virtual_network_name}"
  address_prefix = "192.168.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name = "test"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "test" {
  name = "test"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"

  type = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp = false
    sku = "Basic"

  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.test.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.test.id}"
  }

  vpn_client_configuration {
    address_space = [ "10.2.0.0/24" ]

    root_certificate {
      name = "DigiCert-Federated-ID-Root-CA"
      public_cert_data = <<EOF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=
EOF
    }

revoked_certificate {
      name = "Verizon-Global-Root-CA"
      thumbprint = "912198EEF23DCAC40939312FEE97DD560BAE49B1"
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform v0.11.7

- provider.azurerm v1.13.0

It works well on my site and you can change the resources into yours. For more details about virtual network gateway with Terraform, see [azurerm_virtual_network_gateway](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network_gateway.html).